# client-server using UDP on Android emulator

Tags: android, udp

Is it possible to send/receive UDP packets on an Android emulator? I read somewhere that the ports have to be directed. Could someone explain how it works?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to send and receive UDP packets from android.

Sending part is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652261/how-to-use-udp-sockets-in-android)!