# Android Studio connecting to localhost in mobile

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, android-studio

I just wanted to ask how to connect to the localhost when the app is installed in mobile? I tried installing the apk of the android app in my mobile phone instead of the emulator of android studio. My app has a login and register activity. In the emulator, I'm able to register and login while I cannot register and login using my phone. Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing webserver running within Eclipse from outside the workstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621796/accessing-webserver-running-within-eclipse-from-outside-the-workstation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)

Comment: Edit your question and add the new changes you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers exist, but in simple follow the steps below.

1. First try to connect both your pc and mobile devices in the **same network**.
2. Then find the **ip** of your pc (run `ipconfig` in command prompt if you are using a pc).
3. Place this ip as your **base url** in your app and use **register/login**  endpoints as per your need.

   For eg: **http://your.ip.here/register.php**  like this > (http://192.168.0.2/register.php)
4. Now run the app, it'll connect to the above said ip.

Comment: No offense but sometimes I'm really baffled how many people develop network apps without knowing any networking basics like this!?

Comment: I think they don't like to study the basics first. In my experience a good developer should be a good learner too.